# Unexplained sustained space used in the TempDB log file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, tempdb

A few days ago the amount of used space in both the `tempdb` data and log files started growing rapidly.  After 30 minutes, the `tempdb` log remained around 99% space used for about 7 hours.  Towards the end of the 7 hour period, `I:\Databases\templog.ldf: Operating system error 112(There is not enough space on the disk.) encountered.` was logged followed by about 30 instances of `The transaction log for database 'tempdb' is full due to 'ACTIVE_TRANSACTION'` over a 3 second period, and then suddenly the `tempdb` log file returned to 1% used space.  This usage data is recorded in logs every 3 minutes via a SQL agent job.

I also have a SQL agent job that runs `sp_WhoIsActive` every 1 minute and captures the output.  I don't see anything that stands out in this data that explains what was consuming or holding space in the `tempdb`.  There are some maintenance jobs running for several minutes at a time, typically running no longer than 5 or 10 minutes each.  **Even if one of those jobs or another session used up `tempdb` log space, I would expect the space to be reclaimable after any transactions complete or at least after the session ends**.

- It's a 200 GB drive dedicated for `tempdb` data and log files.
- Both the data and log files grew during this time until there was no more space on disk.
- There's a `tempdb_2.ndf` file I don't recall seeing before (maybe it's always been there...).  `tempdb.mdf` and `tempdb_2.ndf` are the same exact size, around 29 GBs each.  `templog.ldf` is using 137 GBs.
- Running Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU15-GDR) (KB4505225) - 14.0.3192.2 (X64)

I'm trying to understand what happened and how to prevent it again.

- Is it possible for `tempdb` log space to not be reclaimable for hours even if there are no sessions running for anywhere near that long?
- What caused `tempdb` log space used to suddenly free up 3 seconds after the above error messages (not enough space on disk and `tempdb` transaction log is full)?
- Is `sp_WhoIsActive` logging not enough to capture what process was holding onto the `tempdb` log space, what other additional logging can I do?
- If the `tempdb` log space used was actually reclaimable but a glitch in SQL Server prevented it from clearing out, is there a T-SQL command I can run to try and free up available space in the log?

Any thoughts or suggestions are very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible for `tempdb` log space to not be reclaimable for hours even if there are no sessions running for anywhere near that long?

While it's probably possible, I would say under normal circumstances the answer is no.  In the absence of long-running transactions or long-lived sessions, the `tempdb` log should clear pretty quickly.

> What caused `tempdb` log space used to suddenly free up 3 seconds after the above error messages (not enough space on disk and `tempdb` transaction log is full)?

The most likely explanation is that there was a long-running transaction.  It finally encountered this error and was killed, which allowed the log space to free up.

> Is `sp_WhoIsActive` logging not enough to capture what process was holding onto the `tempdb` log space, what other additional logging can I do?

I would expect that to capture it.  One thing that might have caused you to miss it is if the process had executed statements in a transaction and then just stopped doing anything (without committing, rolling back, or disconnecting).

This would be the case if someone ran a query in SSMS that used a ton of `tempdb`, and then just left that SSMS window open all day.  These queries (that are holding resources, but not doing anything actively) won't show up in `sp_WhoIsActive` by default.  You need to add the `@show_sleeping_spids = 2` option to see those.  Here's an excerpt from the built-in docs:

[image: screenshot of show_sleeping_spids option description]

> If the `tempdb` log space used was actually reclaimable but a glitch in SQL Server prevented it from clearing out, is there a T-SQL command I can run to try and free up available space in the log?

Not that I can think of.  You might try issuing a `CHECKPOINT`, to force the VLFs to clear:

```
USE [tempdb];
GO
CHECKPOINT;
```

Comment: Thanks Josh for your input.  Great tip on `CHECKPOINT`, I'll incorporate that into my log usage job and try running it if `tempdb` used space reaches 70%+ (this situation with the `tempdb` log growing to large percentages occurs about once a month).  The `@show_sleeping_spids = 2` parameter for `sp_WhoIsActive` also looks helpful.  Since it outputs a lot of sleeping sessions with that option on, think I'll use it and delete any rows from the `sp_WhoIsActive` output which have `open_tran_count`, `tempdb_allocations` and `tempdb_current` all at `0`.

Comment: @[JoshDarnell] another one of these incidents occurred, fortunately this time I found out about it while it was ongoing thanks to an email alert I added.  This time (possibly before too), it was a **system SPID** that was holding open a long running transaction.  I discovered system processes can be captured in `sp_WhoIsActive` by adding `@show_system_spids = 1`.  For reference, I posted a new [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/281868/system-spid-running-for-hours-filling-up-the-tempdb-log) with a few details gathered (not many though).

Comment: @BenAmada That's a really interesting follow-up question you put up.  I've not come across that we're "sort_init" system spid activity, but I'll be interested to see if anyone else has ideas for you.