# System SPID running for hours filling up the TempDB Log

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, tempdb

I've been trying to track down the source of my `tempdb` log filling up every few weeks where the `tempdb` log space used will continue to grow until it reaches 99% and stays there for hours while the log file grows.  After adding in some additional logging and email alerts, I think I identified the source of the problem, at least for this incident, not sure if the cause is the same in past incidents.

`dbcc opentran` in the `tempdb` reported this:

```
Oldest active transaction:
    SPID (server process ID): 47s
    UID (user ID) : -1
    Name          : sort_init
    LSN           : (41:3017:42)
    Start time    : Dec 19 2020 10:03:20:410AM
    SID           : 0x01
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.
```

The `spid` is `47s` which I discovered is a **system spid**.  I ran `sp_WhoIsActive` with `@show_system_spids = 1` which brought back data on the process.  After running `sp_WhoIsActive` over the course of an hour, `tempdb_allocations` ended up at `4,221,088`, `tempdb_current` was `4,128,656`, `open_tran_count` was `1` (throughout the entire incident) and `sql_text` was always `null`.  After running out of ideas, I ended up restarting SQL Server.  Several times prior to restarting SQL server, I issued a `checkpoint` in `tempdb` but that didn't help, likely since the transaction from the system process was still active.

The `Start time` from the `dbcc opentran` output is 10:03am and it was 1:00pm when I restarted SQL Server.  I ran `dbcc opentran` a few times over the course of an hour and the same output was returned each time.

In this particular case, the server was rebooted and it restarted at 10:02:54 -- 26 seconds before this long running system process started at 10:03:20.  Past incidents don't appear to have happened immediately after a system reboot. I don't have many details on past incidents, but at least the last time this occurred 9 days ago, in the `sp_WhoIsActive` output I collected (without `@show_system_spids` set to `1`) there were no long running processes captured which likely means it was a similar system process running / filling up the `tempdb` log.  This 99% full `tempdb` log incident 9 days ago was ongoing for 7 hours.

Nothing stands out in the SQL Server log and Windows logs.  I'm running Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU15-GDR) (KB4505225) - 14.0.3192.2 (X64).

**Is there a way to determine what a system SPID is doing?  Or any tips on how I can better troubleshoot this problem when it happens next time?** The only clue from this incident is the `Name` value of `sort_init` in the `dbcc opentran` output which could be helpful but seems generic at the same time.

Comment: You're almost 2 years behind on patches - I'd start with a CU update. Do the SQL Server logs have an indication of what it was doing around 10:03?

Comment: @LowlyDBA true haven't updated for a while, I'll give that a try.  I looked through the SQL Server logs and don't see anything that stands out.  Records logged around +/- 10:03 are normal startup messages.

Comment: Upgraded to SQL 2017 CU22 (the latest).  Will continue monitoring to see if this happens again.  It could be up to a few weeks based on how frequently this occurs -- on average about once a month.

Answer (score 1):

There are some newer DMVs designed specifically for troubleshooting what is happening in TEMPDB. Take a look at sys.dm_db_session_space_usage and sys.dm_db_task_space_usage. See [this link for a discussion of those DMSVs](https://codingsight.com/monitoring-tempdb-using-key-dynamic-management-views/)

Comment: Thanks @Lee, I'm using `sys.dm_db_task_space_usage` via the first query in [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/19871/30728).  You're right, this is useful and while this problem was occurring, the DMV/query reported the System SPID was using a lot of `tempdb` space.  `sp_WhoIsActive` reported similar `tempdb` usage by the session.  The main thing that was missing was the `APPLY`s to `sys.dm_exec_sql_text` and `sys.dm_exec_query_plan` didn't report back any query text or plans (they were both `null`).  So I couldn't tell what the system SPID was doing.